# Is it "What should he have done?" or "had he done"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, modal-verbs, infinitives

> - What should he have done?
> - What should he had done?

Could you tell me which one is correct? (If any.)

Answer (score 7):

What you want is

> **What should he have done?**

Keep in mind that your basic present indicative form is **He should [VERB]**, where the lexical VERB is in the *infinitive*, uninflected form. For instance:

> He should **throw** the ball.
>   He should **work** harder.
>   He should **do** this.

When you make a question of this, you put your interrogative at the front, keep the modal verb *should* in second place, and move the Actor, *he*, after the modal verb:

> What should he throw?
>   How should he work?
>   What should he do?

Now—when you cast your basic form into the past, you employ the *present perfect* form, using the *infinitive* of the auxiliary HAVE plus the *past participle* of the lexical verb:

> He should **have thrown** the ball.
>   He should **have worked** harder.
>   He should **have done** this.

And the process of turning that into a question is the same as before—put your interrogative at the front, keep the modal verb *should* in second place, and move the Actor, *he*, after the modal verb:

> What should he have thrown?
>   How should he have worked?
>   What should he have done?

Comment: I edited the OP to show what I thought was intended.

Comment: @BarrieEngland  Thanks - that must have happened while I was writing! I've edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

You can only say the first. That is because a modal verb such as *should* is followed by the plain form of the verb such as *have*, and not by an inflected form such as *had*.